# How can I link my C program against the Arb library?

Tags: compiling, c

I tried to compile the program [Testing Li’s criterion](http://fredrikj.net/blog/2013/03/testing-lis-criterion/) in Ubuntu. However, when I do `gcc demo.c`, I get the output as,

```
demo.c:2:19: fatal error: fmpcb.h: No such file or directory
 #include "fmpcb.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

How can I compile that program? I think I need some bash-script to make the  compilation to work.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to grab and install a library from the same website: http://fredrikj.net/arb/

Comment: Did you check the [github account of the author](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/arb/tree/master/arb)? I believe you need more files to compile the demo program.

Comment: And you might need [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/)

Comment: I tried to install arb first but I still have problems on compiling.

Comment: mpmath? Isn't it a Python package?

Comment: Re: mpmath Yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file fmpcb.h no longer exists in the most recent version of Arb. The fmprb_t and fmpcb_t types in Arb 1.x were obsoleted by the (more efficient) arb_t and acb_t types in Arb 2.x. The most recent release removed the legacy fmpcb_t type entirely.

You should be able to get the code from that blog post working by substituting fmprb -> arb and fmpcb -> acb and possibly making other minor adjustments.

However, a better solution is to use the Keiper-Li example program which is included in Arb:

https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/arb/blob/master/examples/keiper_li.c

This is basically a better version of the program in the blog post. It's faster, supports multithreading, allows you to pass arguments on the command line instead of recompiling, and it should be up to date with the current interface.

From the Arb source directory, you can build and run the example program as follows (assuming Arb has already been installed):

```
cd /home/user/src/arb
make examples
build/examples/keiper_li 100
```

You can also build the library and run example programs without installing Arb, by telling the linker that it can find libarb.so in the source directory:

```
cd /home/user/src/arb
make
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/src/arb:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
make examples
build/examples/keiper_li 100
```

For documentation of the Arb example programs, see: http://fredrikj.net/arb/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

The `fmpcb.h` file cannot be found in the C include path. Besides, [using quotes instead of brackets here is probably a bad idea as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594/2228310). This test your trying to build is probably intended to be compiled **along** with the Arb library, which is why the author is using quotes.

First things first, install the package providing this header file (and of course, the associated library if there is any). This file seems to be provided by the Arb library, which can be [downloaded here (Download ZIP)](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/arb/). Once you have downloaded and extracted the archive, enter its directory and type:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The `configure` script will run checks on your system to make sure it can compile and link the library you're building. If it fails, you will have to install all required dependencies before you go any further. Some dependencies may be provided as binary packages (see your distribution's documentation), some may not (in which case you'll have to read their instructions, usually a README or INSTALL file in the library archive). According to Arb's Git page, you will have a few installs to make:

> Arb depends on FLINT (http://flintlib.org/), MPIR (http://mpir.org)
>   and MPFR (http://mpfr.org). It can be built as a standalone library,
>   or as part of FLINT as an optional extension package.

**Side note:** My Ubuntu system provides binary packages for libflint (libflint-dev) and MPFR (libmpfr-dev). You can install them with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libflint-dev libmpfr-dev
```

(provided your package manager is `apt-get` of course). MPIR can be [downloaded here](http://mpir.org/), and installed using another typical `./configure && make && sudo make install`. According to [the MPIR documentation](http://mpir.org/mpir-2.6.0.pdf), there is no dependency to install before compiling the library. All in all:

- Install `libflint-dev` and `libmpfr-dev` using `apt-get`, or compile them yourself along with their respective dependencies, if they have any.
- Download the MPIR library, compile it (see its README file or the documentation PDF I linked above), and install it.
- Download the Arb library, compile and install it.

Once the Arb library has been built and installed onto your system, the `fmpcb.h` file should be available at `/usr/local/include/fmpcb.h` (except if your distribution uses another path). You will also find the library files in `/usr/local/lib`. Since the header file is in a system directory (C include path), you will have to use brackets instead of quotes in your code:

```
#include <fmpcb.h>
```

Now, if you want to compile and link against this newly installed library, you will have to tell the compiler to do so:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -larb yourprogram.c -o yourprogram
$ ./yourprogram
```

For more information regarding how to install Arb, have a look at [this page](http://fredrikj.net/arb/setup.html). You will also find information regarding the installation of Arb as an extension of Flint, and compiling instructions for this particular situation.

Comment: It still has problems to find fmpcb.h although I have the line `#include <fmpcb.h>` in the code.

Comment: @Jaska Which is the reason why my answer also contains instructions for installing the library properly, and compiling accordingly.